# Scrapy doesn'f follow next-page url, why?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm scraping this website: https://www.olx.com.ar/celulares-telefonos-cat-831 with Scrapy 1.4.0. When I run the spider everything goes well until it gets to the "next-page" part. Here's the code:

```
  # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
#import time

class OlxarSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "olxar"
allowed_domains = ["olx.com.ar"]
start_urls = ['https://www.olx.com.ar/celulares-telefonos-cat-831']

def parse(self, response):
    #time.sleep(10)
    response = response.replace(body=response.body.replace('<br>', '')) 
    SET_SELECTOR = '.item'
    for item in response.css(SET_SELECTOR):
        PRODUCTO_SELECTOR = '.items-info h3 ::text'
        yield {
            'producto': item.css(PRODUCTO_SELECTOR).extract_first().replace(',',' '),
            }

    NEXT_PAGE_SELECTOR = '.items-paginations-buttons a::attr(href)'
    next_page = response.css(NEXT_PAGE_SELECTOR).extract_first().replace('//','https://')
    if next_page:
        yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page),
            callback=self.parse
            )
```

I've seen in other questions that some people added `dont_filter = True` attribute to the `Request` but that doesn't work for me. It just makes the spider loop over the first 2 pages.
I've added the `replace('//','https://')` part to fix the original href that comes without `https:` and can't be followed by Scrapy.
Also, when I run the spider it scraps the first page and then returns `[scrapy.dupefilters] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET https://www.olx.com.ar/celulares-telefonos-cat-831-p-2> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)`
Why is it filtering the second page like duplicated when apparently is not?

I applied the Tarun Lalwani solution on the comments. I missed that detail so bad! It worked fine with the correction thank you!

Comment: Its strange code. Why you need .replace('//','https://') if you use response.urljoin? Please provide all code of spider.

Comment: I've already tried without the https part and gets the same result so there's not the problem. There's something I'm missing about the webpage or my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the css selector. On page 1 it matches the next page link. On page 2 it matches the previous page and the next page link. Out of that your pick the first one using `extract_first()`, so your just rotate between first and second page only

Solution is simple, you need to change css selector

```
NEXT_PAGE_SELECTOR = '.items-paginations-buttons a::attr(href)'
```

to

```
NEXT_PAGE_SELECTOR = '.items-paginations-buttons a.next::attr(href)'
```

This will only identify next page url only